# Медленная работа индексов mysql

Tags: mysql, myisam

В последние дни заметил, что сайт начал работать очень медленно при определенных запросах (match against поиск) .

До этого  годами работал стабильно и быстро.
Я обычно делаю Optimize таблиц раз в неделю и все хорошо и быстро работает. Но теперь "эффект" длится буквально 20 минут, после чего запрос становится опять медленным.
Далее, ночью, когда система пытается делать бекап, таблица крашится.

Подскажите, на что обратить внимание ? полагаю, что тут проблема с индексами, только непонятно, почему щас начались проблемы, ведь ничего не менялось в конфигах и объемах баз.

Comment: Дропнуть и пересоздать FTI.

Comment: Я не специалист в MySQL и в полнотекстовом поиске, но ваше описание появления проблемы мне напоминает то, с чем не раз встречался. Допустим в БД есть что-то плохо оптимизированное изначально или требующее  значительных ресурсов для выполнения. Пока этому слабому месту хватает ресурсов (оперативка под всякие кэши, не нагруженные система ввода-вывода и ЦПУ)  оно работает сносно. Но как только появляется что-то, что начинает забирать ресурсы под себя, 1е резко начинает проявлять свои вообщем-то врождённые недостатки. А что бы побороть проблему, обычно приходится оптимизировать и 1е и 2е.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html) каждого медленного запроса.
Включите [verbose режим](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-application-log-verbose.html) Mysql и отлавливайте ошибки в логах.